# r comparing string values from two dataframes

Tags: r, compare, match

I have two datasets look like below:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Grade = c("G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3"),
                  names = c("Harper","Mason","Evelyn","Ella","Avery",
                            "Jackson","Olivia","Isla","Emily","Poppy"))
    > df1
   Grade   names
1     G3  Harper
2     G3   Mason
3     G3  Evelyn
4     G3    Ella
5     G3   Avery
6     G3 Jackson
7     G3  Olivia
8     G3    Isla
9     G3   Emily
10    G3   Poppy

df2 <- data.frame(Grade = c("G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3","G3"),
                  names = c("Harper","Mason","Ava","Avery","Isabella",
                            "Jessica","Emily"))
> df2
  Grade    names
1    G3   Harper
2    G3    Mason
3    G3      Ava
4    G3    Avery
5    G3 Isabella
6    G3  Jessica
7    G3    Emily
```

In a new data frame, I would like to save four information:

> (a) the common names,
>   (b) unique names in df1,
>   (c) unique names in df2, and 
>   (d) counts for each column.

so the dataset should look like this:

```
> final
  Grade common.names unique.df1 unique.df2
1    G3       Harper     Evelyn        Ava
2    G3        Mason       Ella   Isabella
3    G3        Avery    Jackson    Jessica
4    G3        Emily     Olivia       <NA>
5    G3         <NA>       Isla       <NA>
6    G3         <NA>      Poppy       <NA>
7 Count            4          6          3
```

I tried to `compare()` from `library(compare)` but that does not seem to work for finding the common names.

```
comparison <- compare(df1,df2,allowAll=TRUE)
comparison$tM

> comparison$tM
  Grade   names
1    G3   AVERY
2    G3    ELLA
3    G3  EVELYN
4    G3  HARPER
5    G3 JACKSON
6    G3   MASON
7    G3  OLIVIA
```

Any thoughts on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function:

```
join <- function(x,y)
{
  join_by = intersect(names(x),names(y))
  a <- data.table::transpose(dplyr::inner_join(x,y,join_by))
  b <- data.table::transpose(dplyr::anti_join(x,y,join_by))
  d <- data.table::transpose(dplyr::anti_join(y,x,join_by))

  counts <- setNames(lengths(e <- list(a,b,d)),
                     c("common.names", "unique.df1", "unique.df2"))

  f <- do.call(plyr::rbind.fill,e[y<-order(counts,decreasing = TRUE)])

  s <- data.table::transpose(f)[-c(3,5)]
  setNames(s,c("V1",names(counts[y])))[c(1,y+1)]
}

join(df1,df2)
  V1 common.names unique.df1 unique.df2
1 G3       Harper     Evelyn        Ava
2 G3        Mason       Ella   Isabella
3 G3        Avery    Jackson    Jessica
4 G3        Emily     Olivia       <NA>
5 G3         <NA>       Isla       <NA>
6 G3         <NA>      Poppy       <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option where we split the datasets by 'Grade' (assuming there are multiple 'Grade' values), loop over the `list`s with `Map`, get the common, unique elements in both datasets (`intersect`, `setdiff` - corresponding functions), create a `data.frame` with `cbind.fill` (from `rowr`) and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
library(rowr)
lst1 <- split(as.character(df1$names), df1$Grade)
lst2 <- split(as.character(df2$names), df2$Grade)
out <- do.call(rbind, unname(Map(function(x, y, z) {
     cn <- intersect(x, y)
     un1 <- setdiff(x, y)
     un2 <- setdiff(y, x)         
     cbind(Grade = z, cbind.fill(cn,  un1, un2, fill = NA))
     }, lst1, lst2[names(lst1)], names(lst1))))
names(out)[-1] <- c("common.names", "unique.df1", "unique.df2")
out[] <- lapply(out, as.character)
rbind(out, c(Grade = 'Count', colSums(!is.na(out[-1]))))
#  Grade common.names unique.df1 unique.df2
#1    G3       Harper     Evelyn        Ava
#2    G3        Mason       Ella   Isabella
##    G3        Avery    Jackson    Jessica
#4    G3        Emily     Olivia       <NA>
#5    G3         <NA>       Isla       <NA>
#6    G3         <NA>      Poppy       <NA>
#7 Count            4          6          3
```